# How can I recreate the latest Marshmallow Volume Expand/Collapse Animation?

Tags: android, android-animation, android-6.0-marshmallow

I am implementing an expand/collapse list control. See how the carrot below animates when the volume is expanded or collapsed? I would like to use that exact same animation. Is this `AnimatedVectorDrawable` available anywhere?

[image: Marshmallow Volume Expand/Collapse Animation]

Note - I am okay with this animation only working in 5.0 and above.